# IIS hosted profect on local machine cannot access SQL server database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis

It gives error after publishing site on IIS. I have include the database file before publishing the site. I am trying to access the site locally using localhost or the IP address.
ERROR: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.
)

Comment: What did you find in the Windows Application event log ?

Comment: Cannot get a local application data path. Most probably a user profile is not loaded. If LocalDB is executed under IIS, make sure that profile loading is enabled for the current user.

Comment: Windows API call SHGetKnownFolderPath returned error code: 5. Windows system error message is: Access is denied.
Reported at line: 401.

Comment: that seems pretty clear, then

Comment: how? after 48 hours of searching I didn't find appropriate  solution.....

Comment: "make sure that profile loading is enabled for the current user" and "Access is denied" are the clues. Your site is potentially not executing in the correct user context and therefore doesn't have permission to use the folders it needs on disk.

Comment: See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlexpress/2011/12/08/using-localdb-with-full-iis-part-2-instance-ownership/

Comment: In the ApplicationPool your web app is using, try changing the Process Model -> Identity to LocalSystem

Comment: On changing Identity to LocalSystem nothing happen.

Answer (score 0):

It works after changing Identity to LocalSystem and selecting server name (LocalDb)\v11.0 to INNOVATE8-PC.